# How do I configure Istanbul with maven build

Tags: javascript, maven, istanbul

I have written a java script test case with istanbul. Now I want to integrate it with maven build. Is it possible? If, then please provide me the steps how I can do this.

Comment: Please look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for rules on asking a good question on Stack Overflow.